# How to validate if room number is not in database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Below I have a php code where it will check to see if the room number entered in a textbox is in the database or not.

```
<?php   

$room_there = true;

while( $room_there ){
$roomresult = mysql_query( "SELECT Room FROM Room WHERE Room = " . (int) $_POST['roomChosen']);
if (mysql_num_rows( $roomresult ) == 0)
    $room_there = false;
}; 
?>

<p><strong>Room:</strong> <input type="text" id="room" name="roomChosen" /><br/><span id="roomAlert"></span></p>      <!-- Enter Room here-->
```

Now what I want to know is how do I create a vlaidation for this. My validation works in javascript and if it is met then it should display a message such as "Room number is invalid" else display "" which is nothing.
How can I validate if room number not in database is met?

Below is an example of my validation if the room number textbox is empty to show how I display my validation messages:

```
function validation() {

        var isDataValid = true;

        var roomTextO = document.getElementById("room"); 

    //this retrieves an element from the textbox where user enters in a room number

        var errRoomMsgO = document.getElementById("roomAlert");

     // this is where the alert message appears for validation



   if (roomTextO.value == "") {
          errRoomMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Enter in a Room Number";
          isDataValid = false;
   } else if (!trimmedRoomText.length) {
          errRoomMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Enter in a Room Number"; 
          isDataValid = false;      
   } else {
       errRoomMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
   }

}
```

Comment: If the room exists in the database surely the `while()` will continue infinitely?

Answer (score 3):

Make your php method return json data and then have a javascript perform an Ajax call to get that value. jQuery's $.ajax() method is really easy to use for this type of interaction with PHP.

If the ajax call returns true, do some javascript to show the user that validation was successful, if false, use javascript to show that it was invalid.

Comment: I do apologise but i never used ajax before, can you provide an example of what you have mentioned with any sample code you wish and then i can try and use your example to match my code?

Comment: [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: some simple web searching should turn up plenty of examples on how to handle jquery ajax calls.  you'll want to create a callback method, and then register it with the ajax calls that is fired by your validation method.  you will pass some arguments to your web server via GET arguments, with it looking like "myserver.com/page.php?room=10", and the server/php will return some JSON text, like {"room_id":"10", "valid":"true"}.  it will be a good idea to keep track of the room number both ways.

Comment: Ok I will do some research and see if I can get it working :)